# Change background colour of area behind selected item in Android Bottom Navigation Bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-bottomnav, android-bottom-nav-view

Is it possible to change the background colour of the particular portion of the bar behind the selected item of the bottom navigation bar or any third party libraries that support this?

Also is it possible to add a highlighted bar along the bottom of the selected item like the image below?

See below screenshot:

[image: Bottom Navigation Bar Sample]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `app:itemBackground` attribute of `BottomNavigationView` to do this. The "selected" view is actually *checked*, so keep that in mind when you're creating your state list.

Something like this should work:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/blue" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/gray"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ben P. exactly what I needed

Comment: I've just edited the sample image (with a very bad drawing) with one more thing I'd like to add and not sure if its possible....I basically want to highlight the bottom of the selected item...do you know i that's possible?

Comment: For the `state_checked` drawable, use a `<layer-list>` drawable that has a rect shape and a line at the bottom.

Comment: not working in android newest bottom navigation implementation.

Comment: I also get an error if try to implement it this way in the latest bottom navigation version.